# sending an email with codeigniter doesn't work when they contain a link

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, hyperlink, gmail

I have a script set up that will email a user an activation link when they insert their email into the provided input.

I'm using CodeIgniter's email class to send the multipart emails and the problem I'm having is that when the email is sent, the debugger says that the email was sent sucessfully but the message is never received.

When I send the email to my internal work email, it sends just fine. But when I send it to my gmail account, it never comes through.

I've managed to track down the issue as being a problem with inserting links within the email. When I remove the link, the email sends fine. I put the link back in and the email is never received by my gmail account.

Has anyone ever come accross this problem or do you have any insight into how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

your email is being rejected.. this is no CI issue..

Comment: Yeah, it seems you're right. After some tinkering with the URL, it seems that it only blocks the email when the email contains a specific domain name. When I change the domain name to another of our servers, it works fine. Any idea why it would be blocking the domain that I'm sending the email from?

Comment: its probably spam/blacklisted.

Comment: Yes, gmail checks on SPF records and headers and if anything is not right either it delivers as SPAM or just rejects it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it sounds like the problem isn't with CodeIgniter or your code, but with the server's mail transfer agent sending it on to the Gmail server.

What happens is CodeIgniter puts together an email and gives it to the PHP engine, which passes it on to the mail transfer agent on the server for sending. The MTA will report back to PHP, and therefore CodeIgniter, that it has received the email properly. As PHP & CodeIgniter's jobs are finished at this point, they will report that they've sent successfully.

Check your spam folder in your Gmail to see if it's been put in there..? I haven't used CI for a while so can't remember exactly, but I think there's an HTML-email parameter you may need to set before you send. If so, Gmail might be expecting this to be set too.

Scroll down to 'Email Preferences' here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html and set the mailtype to HTML.

If that doesn't work, you will need to debug fully.

To debug the problem properly you will need to be able to access the MTA logs. Is this a local development server or a live production machine? Is it Linux or Windows? If Linux, which distribution? Do you know which MTA you are using? Do you have SSH access to the server?

If you can get SSH access and find out which MTA you have things will be a lot simpler to find out and you'll be able to monitor the outgoing messages and the destination servers' responses as they happen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is on a remote development server that's running on CentOs. I don't think I'll bother digging too deep with this as this server is strictly for testing. Once it goes live, this system will be on a different server with a different domain name. Thanks for your help.